# Ending up creating HTML incorrectly with in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create this piece of HTML dynamically within a for loop

```
<ul class="restListings">
   <br>
   <sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub>
   <li>
      <h6>Restaurant Name</h6>
       <p>Near Office</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h6>Restaurant Name</h6>
      <p>Near Office</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h6>Restaurant Name</h6>
      <p>Near HDFC Bank, Madhapur, Hyderabad.</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h6>Restaurant Name</h6>
      <p>Near Office</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But i am ending up  creating this HTML

```
<ul class="restListings" style="display: block;">
   <sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant<br>
      <li>
      </li>
      <h6>OhrisHome</h6>
      <p>Near Office</p>
      <li>
      </li>
      <h6>SwagtahtHome</h6>
      <p>Near Home</p>
      <li>
      </li>
      <h6>ParadiseHome</h6>
      <p>Secundrabad</p>
   </sub>
</ul>
```

This is my code which is producing the above

```
var response =
[
    {
        "RestaurantName": "OhrisHome",
        "Locality": "Near Office"

    },
    {
        "RestaurantName": "SwagtahtHome",
        "Locality": "Near Home"

    },
    {
        "RestaurantName": "ParadiseHome",
        "Locality": "Secundrabad"

    }
];

var divhtml = $('<sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub>');
divhtml.append('<br>');

for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
divhtml.append('<li>');
divhtml.append('<h6>'+response[i].RestaurantName+'</h6>');
divhtml.append('<p>'+response[i].Locality+'</p>');
divhtml.append('</li>');
}

$('.restListings').append(divhtml);
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/eb1t5jop/

Comment: Your desired HTML is invalid. Only `<li>` elements can be children of `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you do this:

```
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
    divhtml.append('<li>
        <h6>'+response[i].RestaurantName+'</h6>
        <p>'+response[i].Locality+'</p>
        </li>');
}
```

Or:

```
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
    theHtml = '<li>';
    theHtml += '<h6>'+response[i].RestaurantName+'</h6>';
    theHtml += '<p>'+response[i].Locality+'</p>';
    divhtml.append(theHTML + '</li>');
}
```

And remove the `<sub>` tag from the `<ul>`.